# How to install PostgreSQL 9.2 on CentOS 5?

Tags: postgresql, rpm

PostgreSQL 9.2 isn't available on CentOS (the latest version is 8.1), so in order to get it, one has to add a postgre repository with the command

```
rpm -ivh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-5-i386/pgdg-centos92-9.2-6.noarch.rpm
```

(as per [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-postgresql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) or [that](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1345367231.19699.4.camel@lenovo01-laptop03.gunduz.org)).

However, when I try that, the only answer I get is

> Retrieving http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-5-i386/pgdg-centos92-9.2-6.noarch.rpm
>   error: skipping http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-5-i386/pgdg-centos92-9.2-6.noarch.rpm - transfer failed - Unknown or unexpected error

"Unknown or unexpected error" isn't very helpful.

I've verified that package does exist. How does one debug those rpm errors?

Answer (score 0):

Installed on my box successfully. It is CentOS 6.3, but I don't think that matters. Maybe it's temporary problem. Did you try from other server? You can use yum downloadonly and them transfer the RPM.
Anyway, I installed it and as expected it created a file named /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-92-centos.repo with the following data, so you can do it manually and go on:

---

```
[pgdg92]
name=PostgreSQL 9.2 $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-92

[pgdg92-source]
name=PostgreSQL 9.2 $releasever - $basearch - Source
failovermethod=priority
baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/srpms/9.2/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-92
```